# How to write this calculation in better style?

Tags: javascript

I have those 2 functions each function return a number value, but I don't like the way I made it any idea how to make the code look more Pro especially

```
const fill = (calculateLastDay() - calculatePopulate());
```

looks really awkward even if it works.
thanks.

```js
// get the last day number of the last cell //
function calculatePopulate() {
    let set = document.getElementById('lastBastard');
    let text = set.textContent;
    return text;
}
calculatePopulate();
// Calculate the last day of month // 
function calculateLastDay() {
    var today = new Date();
    var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: 'numeric' });
    return lastDayOfMonth;
}
calculateLastDay();
// Returning a number value of the tow functions for further use  
const fill = (calculateLastDay() - calculatePopulate());
```

Comment: Looks reasonable, there's nothing noteworthily bad about it, though I'd use better variable/function names and use a linter (to avoid `let` and `var`)

Comment: so is it normal to do this ? like substraction a function from another ?

Comment: Sure. Main problem here is that the *intent* of what you're doing isn't very clear. codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Just get the Element once and store it in a higher level variable, then access the Element properties by variable, or a parse has to occur every time you call `calculatePopulate`. There's really no need for that function at all. Just do like `const lastBastard = document.getElementById('lastBastard'); let fill = calculateLastDay()-lastBastard.textContent;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is always better to explicitly convert text to numbers before perform calculations.
2. You don't need to perform a whole `Date` to `string` convertion, you can just use `getDate`.
3. Use `const` everywhere you can.
4. You don't need to call your `calculatePopulate` and `calculateLastDay` right after definition.
5. Use functions composition.
6. Always check elements references if it's null.

```js
// if `lastBastard` element will not change it's ID 
// and if it will not be moved/removed, 
// then we can cache it globally.
// It depends on your app logic
// const set = document.getElementById('lastBastard');


// get the last date number of the last cell
function getLastSavedDate() {
    const set = document.getElementById('lastBastard');
    
    // `set` is possibly `null`
    // so it is up to you to decide what should happen if it's `null`
    if (!set) {
        return NaN;
    }

    const text = set.textContent;
    return +text; // by adding plus sign we converting string to a number
}

// getLastSavedDate() // we don't need call it here!

// Calculate the last day of month
function getLastDate() {
    const today = new Date();
    const lastDateOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);
    return lastDateOfMonth.getDate(); // `getDate` returns `number`
}

// getLastDate(); // we don't need call it here!

// here we using functions composition
function getLastDatesDiff() {
    return getLastDate() - getLastSavedDate();
}



// then somewhere in your code
const fill = getLastDatesDiff();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty good already. A couple of things - naming is essential. You can avoid the weird subtraction of functions by applying semantic naming.

```
// get the last day number of the last cell //
function getLastDay() {
    const set = document.getElementById('lastBastard');
    const text = set.textContent;
    return text;
}

// Calculate the last day of month // 
function getLastDayOfMonth() {
    const today = new Date();
    const lastDayOfMonth = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { day: 'numeric' });
    return lastDayOfMonth;
}

// Store the difference between the two dates
const lastDay = getLastDay(); 
const lastDayOfMonth = getLastDayOfMonth() 
const difference = lastDayOfMonth - lastDay;
```

The names of the functions have been made semantic, and the higher level logic is crystallised at the end of the function, with the implementation above.

This is more maintainable - meaning that you or another programmer in the future will find it easier to understand the code.

See these two articles:

- [Just Say No to Loops and Variables](https://joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/just-say-no-to-loops-and-variables/) (about naming)
- [Shun the Mutant - the case for const](https://joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/shun-the-mutant/) (about `let` vs `const`)